# Can you compare average differences over time as an alternative to mixed models?

Tags: r, mixed-model, panel-data, longitudinal-data-analysis

I have data that looks at the rate of crime for four countries over a three year time period. I would like to see whether the rates per 1000 people for each country are significantly different from one another over the time period. I have attempted to model this data using a variety of multilevel models (e.g. negative binomial with number of offences offset for log population size, poisson with same, normal distribution with rates as my dependent variable, and lognormal with rates as my dependent variable). In all cases, my models fail to converge or become singular fit.

My data with rates looks as such

```
     df<- data.frame(rate=c(16.000584,  1.883443, 16.292833,
      1.901452, 15.854460,  1.908956, 17.425294,  2.009882, 17.534887, 2.079291, 18.594287,  2.011382, 18.082852,  2.018511, 17.534887,  1.935970, 18.448162,  2.056405, 18.411631,
    1.877440, 17.461825,  1.961858, 18.046321,  1.801652, 20.493899,  2.041773, 22.064733,  2.099176,  2.861339, 17.630465,2.734731, 17.348378,  3.063912, 16.925247,  3.076572, 17.771509, 3.215841, 19.605078,  3.063912, 20.451340,  3.355110, 22.566996,  3.443735, 21.720733,  3.342449, 18.335684,  3.013269, 21.297602,  3.367771, 19.322990 , 3.418414, 16.078984,  3.545022, 24.682652),
    country = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,
1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4),
time= c(1,  1 , 2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  4,  5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3, 3,  4,  4,  5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 14, 14))
```

My question is, what alternatives to multilevel modelling would you use if you were interested in seeing whether the rates were significantly larger for one country vs another. Is a comparison of averages problematic (i.e. taking the mean rate over the time period and running a t-test)? alternatively, is it a problem to run multiple chi-squares at each time point looking at differences in proportion of offending for each country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, because you only have four countries it is expected to run into convergence problems if you would put `country` as a grouping factor and add random effects for it.

In your case you could instead fit a standard Poisson or negative binomial model in which you put `country` as a categorical covariate (i.e., a `factor` in R). From the description of your question, you would possibly also want to include the `time` variable and also the interaction between `time` and `country`. Testing for this interaction would tell you if there are differences between countries over time.

With regard to `time` you will need to consider whether you want to put this also as a categorical variable (`factor`) into the model, i.e., assuming no particular relationship between the log rates over time or a continuous variable (`numeric`) in which case you would be assuming a linear relationship of log rates over time.